# Projector’s remote controller events

Tags: winapi, events

I should make a PowerPoint presentation, but I don’t want do it. Instead, I know c++ and WinApi, and I decided to make an app, with cool effects, that would be presentation. In my classroom there is projector with the remote controller.

How can I handle events from the remote controller in my app? Will it be WM_KEYDOWN or something like this when I press next or previously on controller?

Also, can these events be handled in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with serial communication, this work will not be difficult.

A number of projectors have RS232 or USB ports that can be used for controlling the projector's functions, i.e. switching inputs and powering on and off.

Then you only need to know the model of the projector, you can search the corresponding serial communication protocol on the Internet, or directly ask the manufacturer for the protocol information.

[A small blog demo](https://win1337ist.wordpress.com/tag/sending-serial-port-commands-to-projector/)

And you only need to process the buttons of the remote control according to the serial port command.

Cases that might be useful to you:

- [Projector control - RS232 / USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801593/projector-control-rs232-usb)
- [3 EASY STEPS TO UNDERSTAND AND CONTROL YOUR RS232 DEVICES](https://www.commfront.com/pages/3-easy-steps-to-understand-and-control-your-rs232-devices)
- [Control projector via serial port](https://www.ssplash.com/Forums/tabid/76/aff/3/aft/16692/afv/topic/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously hard to say without knowing the model and brand of your projector. Many projectors do present these buttons as a USB keyboard, though (see [one user manual](https://www.projectorcentral.com/pdf/projector_manual_9567.pdf) specifying "page up" and "page down" keys as an example - I'm not affiliated with the brand in any way; it was just the first explicit specification I could find).

I suggest to try it out with the relevant equipment. The following website might be useful to see the keyboard input (and it incidentally answers your second question about the browser): [key event viewer](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html)

Comment: Thanks for feedback